# Validation not firing submitHandler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

As stated in the title, the submitHandler is not firing/being reached, but the validation is working correctly. The submit handler is in the correct, but not firing.

```
$(function () {
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        domain: {
            required: true
        },
        playerClass: {
            required: true,
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        var accountNumber = $("input#accountNumber").val();
        var domain = $("input#domain").val();
        var playerClass = $("input#playerClass").val();
        var dataString = JSON.stringify([{
            "accountNumber": accountNumber,
                "playerClass": playerClass
        }]);
        //Save Form Data........
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: dataString,
            success: function () {
                $('.render-info').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>You've successfully built your player code</div>");
                $(".player-code").show();
            },
            failure: function () {
                alert(dataString);
                $('.render-info').html("<div class='alert alert-failure'>Submission Error</div>");
            }
        });
        $(".player-code").show();
    }
});
});
```

jsFiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/e04rca0t/5/)

Comment: You need to show all relevant content in the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't have a real submit button.  A `div` is not a button...

```
<div class="btn btn-default submit">Submit</div>
```

You need a `button` or `input` with `type="submit"` to trigger the `submitHandler` when the form is valid.

```
<input type="submit" class="submit" />
```

OR

```
<button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e04rca0t/7/

Comment: Yeah, just realized I didn't create it correctly. Need more coffee!